A sufficient condition for a Latin square to be non-associative
Suppose we are given a multiplication table of a binary operation "$*$" on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
* & 1 & 2 & \dots & n \\\hline
1 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
2 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
n & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots
\tag1
\end{array}$$
such that $(1)$ is a Latin square (every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ appears once and only once in each row/column). I think I managed to prove that $(1)$ is associative (and hence the Cayley table of a group) if and only if, for every $i,j,k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$:
$$i*j=k\Longrightarrow \sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_k\tag2$$
where $\sigma_i\in S_n$ is defined by:
$$\sigma_i(j):=i*j\tag3$$
Despite the runtime of the algorithm "$(2)$ after $(3)$" is no better than $O(n^3)$ (like the naive associativity algorithm), from the condition $(2)$ follows, in particular, that:
$$\{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n\}\le S_n \tag4$$
Q. Is the runtime of the algorithm "$(4)$ after $(3)$" less than $O(n^3)$? If so, this approach could serve as a faster preliminary test before going through (possibly unncessarily) any $O(n^3)$ runtime algorithm.

I don’t think so. However, Dietrich and Wilson exhibited a nearly linear time algorithm ($O(n^2 \text{poly} \log n)$) for testing whether a multiplication table forms a group.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9719733
